# How to raise Exception with array?

Tags: python

I tried to throw an exception with array data:

```
 raise Exception([ValidateError.YEAR, row])
```

When I tried to catch it I get this error:

```
'Exception' object is not subscriptable
```

Code is:

```
    except Exception as e:
        #invalid
        print(e[0])
```

Comment: Why do you use brackets (`[]`)?

Comment: It is not list (array)?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `e[0]`, what do you expect that to mean? What should the result be, and why?

Comment: "It is not list (array)?" The code says `except Exception as e:`. This means that the name `e` will be used for an `Exception`. Exceptions are not lists. Why would they be lists? (Hint: are you also surprised that `int('123')[0]` does not work?)

Comment: I need it because in loop I check varaible if it is wrong I reaise exception, then in outside loop I need to get this variable value and exception name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the Exception arguments you passed as a list, you should use `.args`.

So, I believe you were looking for the following:

```
except Exception as e:
   #valid
   print(e.args[0][0])
```

As a side note, you can pass multiple arguments without them being in a list:

```
raise Exception(ValidateError.YEAR, row)
```

And then you need one index less:

```
except Exception as e:
   #also valid
   print(e.args[0])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, why when pass: `raise Exception(ValidateError.DAY, row)` Where ValidateError is:

`class ValidateError(Enum):
    DAY = 1`

I get string `ValidateError.DAY` instead `1`

Comment: @Alina it should still be an Enum. I.e., if you do `type(e.args[0])` you should get `<enum 'ValidateError'>`. It prints just like a string, but it's still your Enum.

Comment: So, I can check `if e.args[0] == ValidateError.MONTH:` right?

Comment: @Alina Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Exception` and implement the `__getitem__` function like so:

```py
class MyException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.l[key]

try:
    raise MyException([1, 2, 3])
except MyException as e:
        print(e[0])
```

running it:

```
python3 main.py 
1
```